# Natural topologies for the space of rational functions

Tags: limits-and-convergence, rational-functions

I am looking for natural families of Hausdorff topologies (metrics, norms, if possible) for the space of rational functions of a single complex variable of arbitrary, unbounded denominator degree (and, if needed, a finite, or zero, limit for $z\to\infty$). Or spaces of meromorphic functions containing these functions.

The main requirement is that any sequence of functions $r_n$ defined by $r_n(z):=a_n/(b_n-z)$ for $z$-independent $a_n\to a\ne 0$ and $b_n\to b$ converges to to the function $r$ defined by $r(z):=a/(b-z)$.

If possible, I'd like to have a metric which gives a nice formula for the distance 
of $a/(b-z)$ to $a'/(b'-z)$.

Comment: As long as you avoid letting $a\to0$, you can just take the distance from $a/(b-z)$ to $a'/(b'-z)$ to be $|b/a-b'/a'|$, I think. But if you want a nice metric topology that's okay for all $(a,b)\in\mathbb C^2$, there may well be a serious problem in the neighborhood the line $a=0$.

Comment: I want a topology on the space of all rational functions of arbitrary denominator degree (and, if needed, a finite limit for $z\to\infty$) with properties that imply the above special cases.

Comment: Not sure if it's quite what you need, but there's a paper by Laura DeMarco, "Iteration at the boundary of the space of rational maps", *Duke Math. Journal.* **130** (2005) 169-197, that might be relevant. In any case, I seem to recall that she considers some sort of inductive (projective?) limit of the space of rational functions of degree $d$ over all $d$. The paper is available here: http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~demarco/Duke_boundary.pdf

Comment: @JoeSilverman: As far as I could see, the paper works throughout with constant degree.

Comment: Okay, but since it's dealing with iteration, and the degree of $f^n$ is $(\deg f)^n$, somehow it needs to be relating maps of differing degrees. In any case, Laura would be a good person to ask about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Karl-Goswin Grosse-Erdmann, The locally convex topology on the space of meromorphic functions, J. Austr. Math. Soc., 59 (1995) 287-303

Comment: Thanks! The description on p. 292 in terms of seminorms is very useful!

Answer (score 5):

What happens with this way of doing it?

A rational function is a map from the Riemann sphere 
$\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ to itself.  The Riemann sphere is compact, so has a unique uniform structure.  (So choose a nice metric for it, say the one from an actual sphere.)  Use "uniform convergence".

This topology is metric.

Comment: What would be the distance of two functions of the form $r(z):=a/(b−z)$?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar It wasn't Arnold that made that remark. (Not that it matters.)

Comment: The difficulty is that in this topology $z/(z-1/n)$ has no limit when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: It seems in this topology, you cannot change the degree when you converge.  Constants can converge to constants.  Degree one maps (like $z/(z-1/n)$) cannot converge to a constant (like $1$).

Answer (score 2):

$\hbox{Rat}_d$, the space of rational functions of degree $d$, is a $2d+1$ dimensional affine algebraic variety, so it embeds into $\mathbb A^N$ for some suffficiently large $N$. Since you're presumably interested in working over $\mathbb C$ (or maybe $\mathbb R)$, you can embed $\hbox{Rat}_d(\mathbb C)$ into $\mathbb C^N$ and then just use the usual topology on $\mathbb C^N$.

To be more precise, if you view a degree $d$ rational function $f(z)=F(z)/G(z)$ as the $2d+2$-tuple of the coefficients of $F$ and $G$, it is defined as a point in $\mathbb P^{2d+2}$, and $\hbox{Rat}_d$ is the complement of the resultant locus $\mathcal R:\hbox{Res}(F,G)=0$. The complement of a hypersurface such as $\mathcal R$ is an affine variety. There's a brief description of how this embedding works in (see especially Proposition 4.27)

*The Arithmetic of Dynamical Systems*, Springer, Section 4.3 "The Space $\hbox{Rat}_d$ of Rational Functions"

**Addendum** in answer to comment that "I need a single space independent of $d$"

Ah, that's much more problematic. Now you're into the whole yoga of degenerations of rational maps of degree $d$ on the boundary of their natural moduli space. For those who work in dynamical systems, it is more natural to look at the quotient space $\mathcal M_d := \hbox{Rat}_d/\hbox{PGL}_2$, where the action is via conjugation, $f^\phi=\phi^{-1}\circ f\circ\phi$. These spaces were studied by Milnor (*Experimental Math* **2**(1), 37-83, 1993), who proves that $\mathcal M_d(\mathbb C)$ is an orbifold and that it has a reasonable compactification. In particular, for $d=2$ he proves that $\mathcal M_2(\mathbb C)\cong\mathbb C^2$, and its natural compactification is $\overline{\mathcal M_2}(\mathbb C)\cong\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$. So then you can take any natural metric on projective space. I took this up from the perspective of algebraic geometry (geometric invariant theory) in *Duke Math J.* **94**(1), 41-77, 1998.  Of course, this may not be what you need, but it provides one approach. The point is that if you want a nice compactification of a moduli space, you usually need to restrict what sort of degenerations are allowed. In GIT language, the magic word is *semi-stability*.

Comment: I need a single space independent of $d$.

Comment: In that case, you can just view the union of all the spaces as a subset of $\mathbb C^\infty$. Thus a sequence of rational functions converges when its coefficients converge.